# How to iterate over each connected components label pixels

Tags: python, opencv, pixel, connected-components

What's the best way to iterate over labels pixel positions in relation to source image retrieved from opencv `connectedComponentsWithStats`? Currently, I'm putting the labels over a blank background the size of the source image like the following and iterative over the source image pixels to find where the labels are located:

```
bg = np.uint8(np.zeros(labels.shape[:2])) 
bg[np.where(labels == 1)] = 255
# Start pixel by pixel iteration on bg, but limited to their bounding box taken from stats
```

but I feel like there must be an easier way doing it without having to put them on a blank background. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: if you just want to speed up, you can iterate over subimages after generating a bounding box.

Answer (score 1):

It was easier than I thought! You can simply iterate labels pixel like this.

```
y = np.where(labels == 1)[1]
x = np.where(labels == 1)[0]
```